# Views need to be explicit from FuelPHP 1.7?

Tags: fuelphp

With no view specificied in FuelPHP 1.6, the default was to load the view located in /views/controller/action but I'm trying FuelPHP 1.7 now and when I don't explicitly forge a view I just get a white output screen. (I checked that is isn't breaking by echoing)

Is this expected behavior? Do views now need to be explicitly called every time?

Comment: What kind of controller are you using? Are you using a `Controller_Template`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was always the expected behaviour. I don't remember FuelPHP having such magic, it must have been your own controller. I even checked out 1.6 to check, and there's no code in `Controller::after` or `Controller_Template::after` that would do anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

FuelPHP has never had any code in the default controller classes that loads views automatically based on the controller and action. It sounds like this is custom behaviour that has been added to your application by either yourself or another developer on your project.

You should check what is in the `before` and `after` methods of your parent controller as it seems that a minor change in 1.7 has broken your application's logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a white output screen, it's actually a normal behavior. You have to forge a view on the methods of your controller.